# Macbook Pro 10.10.5 Can Only Connect to Large Sites like Google, StackExchange, Wikipedia

Tags: network, wifi, safari, dns

This strange connection issue has been very stubborn. In short, after every reboot I can access the entire internet for a short period of time. After a time (say 30 minutes) all but major websites like Google, Facebook, etc timeout in both of my browsers (Safari and Firefox)

*But strangely I am able to ping websites that timeout while loading in the browsers.*

This is an issue on my computer across every network it is connected to using both wifi and ethernet. It is not an issue for any other computers on my home network.

I've tried turning off IPv6 or using Google DNS but no change.

Comment: did you manage to fix this?